# How to detect whether a child_added event is local?

Tags: firebase

In a web app I have this:

```
function onChildAdded(snapshot) {
  // ...
}
someFirebaseLocation.on('child_added', onChildAdded);
```

I'm looking for a 100% reliable way to detect whether the child_added event is immediate, so that I can handle the two cases correctly: when after push() the function gets called immediately (sync) vs when the function gets called async.

Setting a flag before the push() call is not reliable I think. (Potential race condition when an async event comes in, and the flag might not get reset when there's an error).

Another option would be

```
var pushed = push(...);
```

and then in child_added

```
if (snap.name() === pushed)
```

but an incoming message could have the same .name() thus there could be collisions. The probability of a clash is debatable, but I'd prefer a simple and watertight way to get the info.

It would be great if I could do this:

```
function onChildAdded(snapshot, prevChildName, isImmediateEvent) {
  if (isImmediateEvent) {
    // Handle as sync event.
  } else {
    // Handle as async event.
  }
}
someFirebaseLocation.on('child_added', onChildAdded);
```

or this

```
function onChildAdded(snapshot, prevChildName) {
  if (snapshot.isFromImmediateEvent) {
    // Handle as sync event.
  } else {
    // Handle as async event.
  }
}
someFirebaseLocation.on('child_added', onChildAdded);
```

Is there some other reliable option? Otherwise I'll ask the Firebase guys whether they could generally pass a bool "isImmediateEvent" into the callback (after snapshot,prevChildName).

Tobi

Comment: Tobi: hope it's not too late to ask you how did you finally handle this.

Comment: Hi Tobi: In my case, I reorder items in an array using priorities. A single local item move can produce a different number of child_moved and child_changed events. The first fire within 20ms the second between 200ms and 1000ms.

In short I got a variable number of events and a wide response time range. How did you handle that. Did you timeout your solution?

Comment: In general, changing the priority on a single item so its position changes should only produce a single child_moved and a single child_changed event.  And the notes here should be applicable.

Comment: Also, this jsfiddle (not by me) might be helpful: https://jsfiddle.net/natzcam/o67u30ve/ . You can test by opening 2 tabs, sending a message on one, then looking at the console of both tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've covered the two options for now and either one should work reliably (see notes below).  We might add features in the future to make this easier, but nothing concrete is planned at this point.

A couple notes:

1. Setting a flag should work fine.  No async events will happen until after your synchronous code has finished running.  You can avoid the error issue by using a try/finally block to reset it.
2. push() id's are designed to be universally unique, so you really shouldn't worry about conflicts.